# how to pass multiple IDs in a URL at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that when an item is clicked it passes an ID to the following function,

```
function navigateLink(id) {
            var url = '/' + 'List/events/';
            if (id)
                url += id;
            else if (markets.length > 0) {
                url += markets.toString();
            }
            $.history.load(url);


        }
```

a single ID will get passed into my URL for example if my ID is 111 then my URL based on above will be `http://localhost:/#/List/events/111`,This works fine. what i would like to know is that is there a way i can pass 2 or more IDS in one URL.so if i have IDS 111 and 112 it would normally be passed separate as follows,`http://localhost:/#/List/events/111 
http://localhost:/#/List/events/112`

how can i join both the IDs in one url?

Comment: You said you want one URL but your example of what you want shows 2 URLS, one for each ID. Is this really what you meant?

Comment: How are you expecting to simultaneously load two URLs in one window...?

Comment: no sorry i phrased it wrong, i want it to be passed in one URL,i was just showing how two ids get passed currently

Comment: So you want something like: `http://localhost:/#/List/events/111/112`? Please be clear on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of ids instead of just one, so your function will look something like this:

```js
function navigateLink(ids) {
      // Loop through the IDs
      for(key id in ids) {
        // Get the current ID
        var id = ids[key];
        
        var url = '/' + 'List/events/';
        if (id)
            url += id;
        else if (markets.length > 0) {
            url += markets.toString();
        }
        $.history.load(url);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your backend.

You can `var url = '/' + 'List/events/123-124';`

And then split them:

```
$ids= explode("-", $id);
```